# Understanding select from channels with and without goroutine

Tags: select, go, closures, channel, goroutine

Hello stackoverflow community,
I am using [github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify](http://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify) to set watchers to a file in Go. My function looks like

```
func SetWatcher(filename string) {
    fmt.Println("Setting watcher to file ", filename)
    Watcher, err = fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("inotify errored. Other methods needs to be implemented.")
        panic(err)
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case event := <-Watcher.Events:
                if event.Op == fsnotify.Remove {
                    fmt.Println("File removed, needs to kill the process.")
                } else if event.Op == fsnotify.Rename {
                    fmt.Println("File renamed, need to restart seeking.")
                }

            case err := <-Watcher.Errors:
                log.Println("error:", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    err = Watcher.Add(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    <-done
}
```

which works so far and I get outputs as

```
Setting watcher to file  /var/log/syslog
File renamed, need to restart seeking.
```

However, if I try to remove the closure running in the goroutine and run it as

```
func SetWatcher(filename string) {
    fmt.Println("Setting watcher to file ", filename)
    Watcher, err = fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("inotify errored. Other methods needs to be implemented.")
        panic(err)
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    //defer Watcher.Close()

    //done := make(chan bool)
    //go func() {
    //  for {
            select {
            case event := <-Watcher.Events:
                if event.Op == fsnotify.Remove {
                    fmt.Println("File removed, needs to kill the process.")
                } else if event.Op == fsnotify.Rename {
                    fmt.Println("File renamed, need to restart seeking.")
                }

            case err := <-Watcher.Errors:
                log.Println("error:", err)
            }
        //}
    //}()

    err = Watcher.Add(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    //<-done
}
```

the program never outputs anything. I ran it with `strace` and the program is seen stuck at

```
[pid  5773] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=20000}, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  5772] epoll_wait(4, [], 128, 0)   = 0
[pid  5772] futex(0x598bf8, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  5773] <... pselect6 resumed> )    = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  5740] <... pselect6 resumed> )    = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  5773] futex(0x598578, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, {tv_sec=60, tv_nsec=0} 
<unfinished ...>
[pid  5740] futex(0xae1f58, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, {tv_sec=60, tv_nsec=0}
```

and not receiving from the channel and keeps on waiting.

I've read that this could be caused because of non-buffered channel. So to validate that, I modified the library to use a buffered channel and the part of the function that generates the new watcher looks like

```
    w := &Watcher{
    fd:       fd,
    poller:   poller,
    watches:  make(map[string]*watch),
    paths:    make(map[int]string),
    Events:   make(chan Event, 10), // Made it buffered here
    Errors:   make(chan error),
    done:     make(chan struct{}),
    doneResp: make(chan struct{}),
}
```

But the behavior is the same. Can someone please help me understand why the reading from channel worked when it was in a goroutine, and didn't work without a goroutine?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with fsnotify, but it looks like it won't send anything on the channels until `Watcher.Add()` is called to watch the file, but the `Watcher.Add()` occurs after the `select` in the second version. In this case select will block for ever as nothing can be signaled as `Watcher.Add()` has not been called. Hence there is deadlock.